# How to Design a Chat Bubble and Use It as a Background

Tags: xml, android-drawable, android-studio-2.2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R11dd.png)

I am attempting to create a chat bubble background, but I am facing issues with sizing. What is the correct approach to achieve the proper dimensions?
**I want to design something similar to this shape, similar to the image above.**

```
`<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="150dp"
    android:height="150dp"
    android:viewportWidth="640"
    android:viewportHeight="640">
    <path
        android:pathData="M94.63,265.35C94.63,236.39 118.11,212.92 147.06,212.92L465.54,212.92C494.49,212.92 517.97,236.39 517.97,265.35L517.97,306.48C517.97,335.44 494.49,358.92 465.54,358.92C465.54,358.92 406.99,360.22 378.16,360.86L378.16,360.86C353.14,361.41 329.35,371.78 311.9,389.72L298.68,403.31L289.12,392.82L289.12,392.82C269.44,371.23 241.58,358.92 212.36,358.92C190.81,358.92 147.06,358.92 147.06,358.92C118.11,358.92 94.63,335.44 94.63,306.48z"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:fillColor="#1E1E1E"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000"
        android:strokeLineCap="butt"/>
</vector>`
```

Comment: STACKOVERFLOW.Very stupid and I don't want to use it again